# SwiftUI debugging taps on List cell with NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swiftui

I tried to debug taps on List cells with NavigationLink inside.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SearchWordsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: SearchWordsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBarView(barText: "Search english words for translate",
                              searchText: $viewModel.searchText)
                // ActivitiyIndicator while downloading
                if viewModel.isPageLoading && viewModel.translatePage == 1 {
                    Spacer()
                    ActivitiyIndicator()
                    Spacer()
                } else {
                    translationList
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(
                "Searching",
                displayMode: .inline)
        }

    }
    
    private var translationList: some View {
        List(viewModel.dataSource) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: self.meaningDestination(with: item)) {
                self.createTranslationCell(item)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Cell's NavigationLink's destination
    private func meaningDestination(with data: PosibleTranslation) -> some View {
        LazyView(
            MeaningView(text: data.text)
                .environmentObject(MeaningViewModel(meanings:  data.meanings)))
    }
    
    // Paging
    private func createTranslationCell(_ translation: PosibleTranslation) -> some View {
        TranslationCell(translation: translation)
            .onAppear() {
                if self.viewModel.dataSource.isLast(translation) {
                    self.viewModel.loadNewPage()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My code totally work correct, by I try to handle taps on cell, If it were UIKit I'll set breakpoint on selector method or on destanation controller init.

I try to set breakpoint on MeaningView body, and when I taped on cell, I got the next stack:

[image]

It surprised me, maybe Navigation Link works like deepLink?
And after that, how can I track the tap on the cell, maybe It's need watchpoint?

Comment: SwiftUI has reactive nature. In majority of cases you don't see events (like tap), you see reaction (like refresh). So when you tap NavigationLink, SwiftUI, internally, modifies some state which result in `MeaningView.body` (which is a computed property) rendering, that's why you get into `MeaningView.body.getter`. So... Let's start from the end - why do you need that?

Comment: @Asperi It's not cool that the entire implementation is hiding behind the walls of the framework. There are situations when you need to know exactly at what moment the tap was made and what call stack came to this.  Does this mean that SwiftUI encapsulates all connections between views and we cannot trace these connections?